# Powershell Import CSV with folders/subfolders tree and copy to a new directory without duplicating

Tags: powershell, robocopy

So I have a csv such as:

```
Source
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance\BMc's Files
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance\BMc's Files\2001 Files
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance\BMc's Files\2001 Files\Misc
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance\BMc's Files\2001 Files\Misc\Doc1.docx
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance\BMc's Files\2001 Files\Misc\Doc2.docx
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance\BMc's Files\2001 Files\Misc\Doc3.docx
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance\BMc's Files\2001 Files\Misc\Doc4.docx
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance\BMc's Files\2001 Files\Misc\Doc5.docx
```

When trying to copy over using any copy command, it is of course going line by line and copying each path/file to the new directory. My question is how to make it smart enough to only copy the top level folder and skip the folders/files in the lines below that top level folder.

The example above should recreate

```
c:\users\barcalac\desktop\source\finance
```

to

```
d:\users\barcalac\desktop\target\finance
```

without having all lines copied one by one creating duplicates of what is already in the Finance folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that You are copying each path recursively.
I'm sure it can be done in a smarter way, but this should work.
To remove the paths that are contained in any other path in the document I would do something like this

```
    $a=@"
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance\BMc's Files
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance\BMc's Files\2001 Files
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance\BMc's Files\2001 Files\Misc
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance\BMc's Files\2001 Files\Misc\Doc1.docx
C:\users\fayo\1
c:\users\fayo\2
c:\users\fayo\2\doc.doc
"@|ConvertFrom-csv -Header path

foreach ($i in (0..($a.count-1))) 
{
    foreach ($j in (0..($a.count-1))) {
            if ($a[$j].path -like  "$($a[$i].path)*")
                 {$a[$j]=$a[$i]}  
            }
}

$a|select -Unique -Property path
```

Result of above is

```
path                                    
----                                    
C:\Users\barcalac\Desktop\SOURCE\Finance
C:\users\fayo\1                         
c:\users\fayo\2
```